# xslt remove duplicate in child and parent node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a the following xml-file type and using a xslt-template I try to create a html-Report:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<testmodule >
  <testgroup>
    <testgroup>
      <testcase >
        <teststep result="pass">=&gt;  
            <CRID Name="Cleese" CR-ID="CR#1234" TimeStamp="20150520 0122" Backcolor="White" />
        </teststep>
        <teststep  result="pass">=&gt;: 
            <CRID Name="Cleese" CR-ID="CR#123" TimeStamp="20150520 0122" Backcolor="White" />
        </teststep>
        <verdict time="" timestamp="" endtime="" endtimestamp="" result="pass" />
        <ident>Testcase1</ident>
        <CRID Name="Cleese" CR-ID="CR#123" TimeStamp="20150520 0123" Backcolor="White" />
      </testcase>
      <testcase >
        <teststep result="pass"> 
            <CRID Name="Cleese" CR-ID="CR#1234" TimeStamp="20150520 0123" Backcolor="White" />
        </teststep>
        <teststep result="pass">=&gt; 
            <CRID Name="Cleese" CR-ID="CR#1234" TimeStamp="20150520 0123" Backcolor="White" />
        </teststep>
        <teststep  result="pass">=&gt; 
            <CRID Name="Cleese" CR-ID="CR#1234" TimeStamp="20150520 0122" Backcolor="White" />
        </teststep>
        <verdict  result="pass" />
        <ident>Testcase2</ident>
        <CRID Name="Cleese" CR-ID="CR#1234" TimeStamp="20150520 0123" Backcolor="White" />
      </testcase>
      <testcase >
        <testlogfile file="" />
        <teststep  result="pass">=&gt; Result: 
            <CRID Name="Cleese" CR-ID="CR#123" TimeStamp="20150520 0123" Backcolor="White" />
        </teststep>
        <verdict  result="pass" />
        <ident>Testcase3</ident>
        <CRID Name="Cleese" CR-ID="CR#1234" TimeStamp="20150520 0123" Backcolor="White" />
      </testcase>
      <title>1.3 Group</title>
    </testgroup>
    <title>1. Group</title>
  </testgroup>
  <verdict time="" timestamp="" endtime="" endtimestamp="" result="pass" />
  <title>Testmodul</title>
</testmodule>
```

What I want to achieve is to remove the duplicate Entries with the attribute of CR-ID in the html-file. I tried to use the "Muenchian Method" but literally failed at it.

So I saw another code-snippet and tried to adapt it but it does not work. It removes all duplicates but I want to only remove the duplicates afected per testcase.
Here is a part of the .xslt-Template:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>
         <xsl:template match="testcase" mode="overview">
                <xsl:for-each select="descendant::CRID[not(@CR-ID=preceding::CRID/@CR-ID)]">
                    <xsl:if test="@CR-ID !=''">
                        <xsl:element name="br"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@CR-ID" />
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:template>
```

The problem I have is that the attribute "CR-ID" can be found as Child in "teststep" or in "testcase". So some entries are entirly removed.

The wanted output would be to only give me the following entries in my html:

- testcase 1: Only CR#1234, CR#123
- testcase 2: Only CR#1234
- testcase 3: Only CR#1234, CR#123

Html Code should be like:

```
<td>1.1.1</td>
            <td >Testcase1</td>
            <td ><br>CR#1234<br>CR#123</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td >1.1.2</td>
            <td >Testcase2</td>
            <td ><br>CR#1234</td>
            <td >-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td >1.1.3</td>
            <td >Testcase3</td>
            <td ><br>CR#1234<br>CR#123</td>
            <td ">-</td>
```

Where the "CR#1234" and "CR#123" are used from the xml-file. Using my posted xslt-code only the testcase1 gets the CR#, the others are blank/empty.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your input isn't well-formed. Please correct it and post the expected output HTML code.

Comment: Just adjusted the code to better describe the problem.

Comment: Are you stuck with XSLT 1.0?

Comment: Yes, sadly... but the solution from Martin Honnen did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Muenchian grouping you need to concat the ident with the attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="group" match="testcase//CRID" use="concat(ancestor::testcase/ident, '|', @CR-ID)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Example</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>       
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="testcase">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(ident, ': ')"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".//CRID[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', concat(ancestor::testcase/ident, '|', @CR-ID))[1])]"/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CRID">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="@CR-ID"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

That transforms

```
<root>
    <testcase>
    <teststep>
        <CRID Name="Cleese" CR-ID="CR#1234"/> 
    </teststep>
        <teststep>
        <CRID Name="Cleese" CR-ID="CR#123"/> 
    </teststep>
        <teststep>
        <CRID Name="Cleese" CR-ID="CR#1234"/> 
    </teststep>
    <ident>Testcase1</ident>
</testcase>
<testcase>
    <teststep>
        <CRID Name="Cleese" CR-ID="CR#1234"/> 
    </teststep>
        <teststep>
        <CRID Name="Cleese" CR-ID="CR#123"/> 
    </teststep>
    <CRID Name="Cleese" CR-ID="CR#1234"/> 
    <ident>Testcase2</ident>
</testcase>
<testcase>
    <teststep>
        <CRID Name="Cleese" CR-ID="CR#1234"/> 
    </teststep>
        <teststep>
        <CRID Name="Cleese" CR-ID="CR#123"/> 
    </teststep>
        <teststep>
        <CRID Name="Cleese" CR-ID="CR#1234"/> 
    </teststep>
    <CRID Name="Cleese" CR-ID="CR#123"/> 
    <ident>Testcase3</ident>
</testcase>
</root>
```

into

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

      <title>Example</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <ul>

         <li>Testcase1: CR#1234, CR#123</li>

         <li>Testcase2: CR#1234, CR#123</li>

         <li>Testcase3: CR#1234, CR#123</li>

      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Best thanks!!!! I just included it and it seems to work. Now I will take a closer look to the concat function.